# Error #2077: This filter operation cannot be performed with the specified input parameters

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmapdata

```
Error #2077: This filter operation cannot be performed with the specified input parameters.
  at flash.display::BitmapData/applyFilter()
```

I got this error message trying to apply a `BitmapFilter` (specifically an inner `DropShadowFilter`) to a `BitmapData` via `.applyFilter`

I've never seen this message before and Googling did not immediately answer the question, and I saw someone confounded as to why it applied to JPEG and not PNG images.  So hopefully this question will help someone else.  I'll include my simple solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [BitmapData.applyFilter documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#applyFilter%28%29), it's fairly obvious what the problem is.  I tried to apply a DropShadowFilter to a BitmapData without transparency (aka, no alpha channel, only 24 bits per pixel.)  The docs state which filters require transparency (replicated here for convenience):

Each type of filter has certain requirements, as follows:

- **BlurFilter** — This filter can use source and destination images that are either opaque or transparent. If the formats of the images do not match, the copy of the source image that is made during the filtering matches the format of the destination image.
- **BevelFilter, DropShadowFilter, GlowFilter, ChromeFilter** — The destination image of these filters must be a transparent image. Calling DropShadowFilter or GlowFilter creates an image that contains the alpha channel data of the drop shadow or glow. It does not create the drop shadow onto the destination image. If you use any of these filters with an opaque destination image, an exception is thrown.
- **ConvolutionFilter** — This filter can use source and destination images that are either opaque or transparent.
- **ColorMatrixFilter** — This filter can use source and destination images that are either opaque or transparent.
- **DisplacementMapFilter** — This filter can use source and destination images that are either opaque or transparent, but the source and destination image formats must be the same.

Creating a `BitmapData` with transparency is easy - it's the 3rd parameter to the constructor:

```
// args are: width, height, is_transparent, default_color
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1024, 768, true, 0xff000000);
```

Note that when you create a transparent BitmapData, you must specify a 32-bit integer for the default color (the 4th parameter).  If you merely specify 0xffffff (24-bit white), you'll get a blank image as the alpha value (the highest 8 bits) are 0.